# Popup menu android

Tags: android

I want to make a popup menu that comes from the action bar. So instead of the icon in the action bar there would be something that says menu, and then when clicked it will trigger this popup. Is this possible?

```
 private void showPopupMenu(View v){
           popupMenu= new PopupMenu(menuActivity.this, v);
              popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
              popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {      
           @Override
           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
           }
          });
              popupMenu.show();
          }
```

Comment: Anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[QuickAction3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

and just specify  the menu button as the anchor